# index numeric vector list for multiple numbers

Tags: r, list, vector, indexing

I have a list with different length vectors of 1s and 2s and I'm trying to pull out vectors based on `nchar` and identity, i.e. `1, 2, c(1,1), c(2,2), c(2,1), c(1,2)`. My problem is to identify vectors for which `nchar > 1` containing the combinations `c(1,1), c(2,2), c(2,1), c(1,2)`.

```
#dummy code

`T1,T2` <- 1
`T2,T1` <- 2
`T2,T3` <- c(2,1)
`T3,T2` <- c(2,2)
`T3,T4` <- c(1,1)
`T4,T4` <- c(1,2)
 lst <- list(`T1,T2`=`T1,T2`, `T2,T1`=`T2,T1`, `T2,T3`=`T2,T3`, `T3,T2`=`T3,T2`, `T3,T4`=`T3,T4`, `T4,T4`=`T4,T4`)

 single <- lst[nchar(lst)==1] # only lists with nchar==1
 multiple <- lst[nchar(lst) > 1] # only lists with nchar > 1

 # identify single lists which contain 1s and 2s
 single_1s <- single[single==1] # single vectors for 1s
 single_2s <- single[single==2] # single vectors for 2s
```

How would I do the same for the multiple lists in my example?

Attempt to identify multiple list containing any of the combinations `c(1,1), c(2,2), c(2,1), c(1,2)`, e.g.

```
multiple[multiple==c(1,1)] # Does not work
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: `multiple[sapply(multiple, function(x) all(x==c(1,1)))]`

Comment: Do you need for all those matches in a list

Comment: Yeah, the plan is to count the number of combinations within the list. Is there a all-in-one solution? :)

Comment: Of course! I'll just have it "open" for others to see for a bit longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `list` of all those vectors that needs to be matched.  Then use `lapply/sapply` and `==` to match each element of `indxlst` with `multiple`

```
 indxlst <- list(c(1,1), c(2,2), c(2,1), c(1,2))
 lapply(indxlst, function(x) 
         multiple[sapply(multiple, function(y) all(y==x))])
```

If you need the `count`

```
 sapply(indxlst, function(x) sum(sapply(multiple,
                              function(y) all(y==x))))
```